# Scala.js jQuery ajax call example

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, this, scala.js

I try to use scala.js, but I can not understand some of things. I shall be grateful for the help.

```
import org.scalajs.dom.raw.HTMLElement
import org.scalajs.jquery.{jQuery => JQ, JQueryAjaxSettings, JQueryXHR}

def tableEvents() =
  JQ("td > a").click { () =>
    JQ.ajax(js.Dynamic.literal(
      `type` = "GET",
      url = "/update",
      data = "id="+({ (x: HTMLElement) => JQ(x).parent().prev().html() }: js.ThisFunction),
      // Not working. How to get "this" element here? 
      // Can I use something like Map or Seq to send of many parameters?
      dataType = "json",
      success = { (data: js.Any, textStatus: String, jqXHR: JQueryXHR) =>
        // how to convert data: js.Any to Json ?
      }
    ).asInstanceOf[JQueryAjaxSettings])
  }
```

I am trying to repeat here the already working JavaScript code:

```
function tableEvents() {
  $("td > a").click(function() {
    $.ajax( {
      type: "GET",
      url: "/update",
      data: {id: $(this).parent().prev().html()},
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        $("#id").html(data.id);
        $("#name").val(data.name);
        $("#score").val(data.score);
      }
    })
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you want the `this` parameter passed to the lambda given to `.click`. Therefore, you have to turn that lambda into a `js.ThisFunction`:

```
JQ("td > a").click({ (thiz: HTMLElement) =>
  // Now You can use thiz
}: js.ThisFunction)
```

Comment: I got json so: val json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)).  Is there no easier way?

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about/trying to do, right now. Anyway, this is probably worth a separate question.

Comment: If you change data: js.Any to data: js.Dynamic I believe you will not have to do the JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)) because it will already be declared as Dynamic